# Flutter add click actions to list and using them

Tags: flutter, dart

in my application i want to make custom list of actions such menus in `Drawer`, i created this simple list of actions and menu itmes

```
List listOfMaps=[];
@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  listOfMaps.add({'name':'menu 1','action':_dashboardClick()});
  listOfMaps.add({'name':'menu 2','action':_aboutUsClick()});
}
```

functions as actions:

```
Function _dashboardClick(){
  print('you clicked on _dashboardClick button');
  return null;
}

Function _aboutUsClick(){
  print('you clicked on _aboutUsClick button');
  return null;
}
```

and i try to show them inside `Column`:

```
Expanded(
  child: Column(
    children: <Widget>[
      ...listOfMaps.map( (item) =>
          ListTile(
            title: Text("${item['name']}"),
            onTap:()=> item['action'],
          ) )
    ],
  ),
),
```

now, in that i can put menu items into `ListTile`, but actions doesn't work

Comment: you need to pass a function, not function result, something like: `'action':_aboutUsClick` (and not `'action':_aboutUsClick()`)

Comment: @pskink it doesn't work

Comment: @pskink i change that to `listOfMaps.add({'name':'menu 1','action':_dashboardClick});` and now, it doesn't work and i don't see any output in console

Comment: now you have to call that function from your `onTap` callback

Comment: @pskink i have that `onTap:()=> item['action'],`

Comment: @pskink i'm sorry, i don't understand me

Comment: just call it, like: `onTap:()=> item['action']()`

Comment: but more simple form is: `onTap: item['action']`

Comment: @pskink this solution doesn't work and i see some outputs during build time

Comment: yes, it works: `child: Builder(
    builder: (ctx) {
      var items = [{'n': 'name 1', 'a': () => print('action 1')}, {'n': 'name 2', 'a': () => print('action 2')}];
      return Column(
        children: items.map((e) => ListTile(title: Text(e['n']), onTap: e['a'],)).toList(),
      );
    }
  ),`
 - here `Builder` is used since i had to create `items` somewhere - in your case you dont have to use it of course, as you can see `onTap: e['a']` works just fine

Comment: @pskink as you said using `Builder` that can be help me to use `onTap: e['a']` without putting `()` end of actions? such as `item['action']()`, and why you used `Builder` ?

Comment: "[...] - here Builder is used since i had to create items somewhere - in your case you dont have to use it of course "

Comment: so does `onTap: e['a']` work?

Comment: without `Builder` - does it work? `Column(children: items.map((e) => ListTile(title: Text(e['n']), onTap: e['a'],)).toList(),)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212139/discussion-between-doldurma-and-pskink).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that while adding in list you are calling method so, even while building widget you can see print message in log. and you are not calling method `onTap`, you have to add `()` behind that.

Following code help you more.

```
 List listOfMaps = [];
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    listOfMaps.add({'name': 'menu 1', 'action': _dashboardClick});  // () removed
    listOfMaps.add({'name': 'menu 2', 'action': _aboutUsClick}); // () removed 
  }

  Function _dashboardClick() {
    print('you clicked on _dashboardClick button');
    return null;
  }

  Function _aboutUsClick() {
    print('you clicked on _aboutUsClick button');
    return null;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Demo"),
      ),
      drawer: Drawer(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            ...listOfMaps.map((item) => ListTile(
                  title: Text("${item['name']}"),
                  onTap: () => item['action'](),  // () added
                ))
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```